# How to improve the speed of dwa in base_local_planner?

Tags: ros, dwa, planner, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [base_local_planer](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=indigo) as local planner. However, with same parameters,  the speed of robot from Dynamic Window Approach(DWA) is smaller than with Trajectory Rollout(TR). The "max_vel_x" is set to be 2.0( m/s) ( with non-holonomic mobile model).  It is easy to reach this maximum speed when controleld by Trajectory Rollout.

However, when paramer "dwa" is set to be true, the maximum value from topic /cmd_vel is about 0.25(m/s) . It is same situation when [dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner?distro=indigo) is used.

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem ? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209538/how-to-improve-the-speed-of-dwa-in-base_local_planner?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your odometry correctly reporting the speed of the robot? If it isn't, the acceleration limit may be limiting the commanded speed.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2015-05-20**:
Thank you for you attention! My project is implemented in a simulating way. Fake_localization is used for robot localization. I have checked out the source code of fake localization. It doesn't need the twist component in  nav_msgs/odometry msg. So twist information is not sent to fake localization

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-20**:
You should implement the twist component in the odometry message.